# Retrieve MenuItem with "special" text in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net

I have a WebControls.Menu which holds several MenuItem.

I can use FindItem to retrieve most of them.

But it doesn't work for the two items which text is more than just a word.

Those two items' text being:

- Save as...
- Add new member

I tried setting the separator to | (pipe character) just to be sure it wasn't just that but it didn't fix my problem.

Is there something wrong when using a space or a dot?

Comment: Is giving them an Id and look for that an option for you?

Comment: Id' like to but there's no ID property for MenuItem.

Comment: Say why are you trying to retrieve them? And what does Menu.Children (or whatever it is called) telling you how it could be named?

Comment: I have to enable/disable/hide/show some menu items. There's no restriction on the text you set (as far as I know).

Comment: I'm not that into the aspx things, since i prefer mvc, but from my experience with SP, i'd use the debugger and look inside how the are named internally.

Comment: MenuItems have a value-Property - you could use that (see MSDN for reference)

Comment: I though FindItem was searching on the Text property, but it's actually the Value field. I must have got confused somewhere. Thank @Grumbler85

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `FindItem` of the Menu-Control uses the `Value` of an `MenuItem` to find it and not the `Text`, set and use that Property to find specific controls.
This also makes the FindItem-Function language-indipendent.

**ASPX**

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" StaticDisplayLevels="3">
  <Items>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Datei" Value="File">
      <asp:MenuItem Text="Neu" Value="New"></asp:MenuItem>
      <asp:MenuItem Text="Öffnen" Value="Open"></asp:MenuItem>
    </asp:MenuItem>
  </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

**C#**

```
Menu1.FindItem("File");
```